# How to fetch form data from a web url which is loaded in webview and display in android toast

Tags: android

I have already created Javascript interface for communication.But it is not fetching data from webview

**script tag added in webpage**

```
<script>
 function sendDataToAndroid(toast) {

  MyFunction.onButtonClick(toast);
 }
 </script>
```

This is the code added in Activity

```
     mWebViewDemo.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, 
    "MyFunction");
    mWebViewDemo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebViewDemo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebViewDemo.loadUrl("http:///url");
    mWebViewDemo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});

   public class ButtonClickJavascriptInterface {
    Context mContext;
    ButtonClickJavascriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onButtonClick(String toast) {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code!

Comment: @pleft I edited my code

Answer (score 0):

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**mypage.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
    <title>HTML Android</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTML Android</h1>
    <input
        type="button"
        value="Button 1"
        onClick="sendDataToAndroid('Button 1 is click')" />

<input
    type="button"
    value="Button 2"
    onClick="sendDataToAndroid('Button 2 is click')" />

function sendDataToAndroid(toast) {
    MyFunction.onButtonClick(toast);
}
```

Finally in **WebViewActivity.java**:

```
@SuppressLint({"NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebViewDemo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    mWebViewDemo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    ButtonClickJavascriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new ButtonClickJavascriptInterface(WebViewActivity.this);
    mWebViewDemo.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "MyFunction");
    mWebViewDemo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebViewDemo.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");

}

public class ButtonClickJavascriptInterface {
    Context mContext;
    ButtonClickJavascriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onButtonClick(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Reference: https://capdroidandroid.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/how-send-data-from-javascript-to-native-android-app/

Comment: I have tried this it is working if the html file is in assets but I m having remote url @Ahana

Comment: try this link: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/

Comment: Now m able to run and see the output in emulator but not in mobile device

Comment: It is exact the same code that is givien in the url http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/ Its running fine in emulator but not in device

Comment: Is there any error in log while run on real device.

Comment: Don’t forget to add internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

Answer (score 0):

```
      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

       //  you can split data from url like this
                String[] separated= url.split("&");
                String s = separated[0];
                String s1 = separated[1];
                String s2 = separated[2];
                String s3 = separated[3];
                String s4 = separated[4]; 
            }

         }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: My question is send input form data from HTML/Javascript to native Android my url is live not in assets @Shanmugam

Comment: you can write listener for onPageFinished() , write whatever you want in that